# Android, build each variant with its GMAPS API KEY

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I will start by saying that I am very new to Gradle, so I apologize if this has already been answered.
My situation, I have two build types :

```
buildTypes {
    prod{
    ...
    }
    demo{
    ...
    }
}
```

and two productFlavours :

```
    clientA{
        applicationId "clientPackageNameA"
    }

    clientB{
        applicationId "clientPackageNameB"
    }
```

my tree is like this

```
src :
    - main:
         -assets
         -gen
         -java
         -res
         AndroidManifest.xml
```

In my manifest I have :

```
<meta-data 
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="GMAPS_KEY" />
```

How I can generate 4 apk with different GMAPS_KEY for each variant :

-clientA.prod

-clientA.demo

-clientB.prod

-clientB.demo

In my understand, placeholder works for flavour or buildType but impossible to mix buildtype and flavour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How I can generate 4 apk with different GMAPS_KEY for each variant

You should put your GMaps key into string resource (and reference this resource from manifest) and then create different resource files for each build you want to make.

Comment: In manifest I put this  in manifest this `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/maps" />` and i create 4 dirs from src src/clientARelease/res/, src/clientADebug/res/, src/clientBRelease/res/, src/clientBDebug/res/ where i put a strings.xml file containing that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><string name="maps">value</string></resources>`. But where I decompil my apk in manifest file i have only @string/maps and not the value defined in strings.xml

Comment: sorry 4 dirs like this : src/[flavour][buildType]/res/values/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use different Maps API keys for different flavors by using manifestPlaceholders as follow:

Step 1: Add your different keys in manifestPlaceholders in app/build.gradle

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            manifestPlaceholders.google_maps_key = "Dev API key here"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            manifestPlaceholders.google_maps_key = "Staging API key here"
        }
    }
```

Step 2: In the AndroidManifest.xml inside the application tag use this code to refer API key as per the flavor

```
<application    
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="${google_maps_key}"/>

</application>
```